# django rest framework generics.CreateAPIView for specific manytomany field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

models.py

```
class Author(models.Model):
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
```

serializer.py

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
class AuthorBookCreateView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Book.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BookSerializer

    ????
```

urls.py

```
path('author/<str:pk>/create-book/', views.AuthorBookCreateView.as_view())
```

How can i define a new book for a specific author?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want to display all the nested authors into your endpoint?

Comment: i want to post new book with specific author, for example post a book for author1. see urls.py

Answer (score 0):

I have done a different approach than you show above.

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Book, Author

class AuthorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ['id','nickname']

class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'authors']
```

viewsets.py

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .serializers import BookSerializer, AuthorSerializer
from .models import Book, Author

class AuthorViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Author.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AuthorSerializer

class BookViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Book.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BookSerializer
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from core.api.viewsets import BookViewSet, AuthorViewSet
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'author', AuthorViewSet, basename='author')
router.register(r'book', BookViewSet, basename='book')

app_name='core'

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('api/', include(router.urls))
]
```

With this approach you will be able to assign books to specified authors:

[image]

Then, since each author has an id, each book will correlate with the assigned author.

Here is the result of the endpoint.

Book: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/book/"

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "The lord of the rings: The Fellowship of the Ring",
        "authors": [
            1
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "The lord of the rings: The Two Towers",
        "authors": [
            1
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "The lord of the rings: The Return of the King",
        "authors": [
            1
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "title": "The Storms of Windhaven",
        "authors": [
            2
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "title": "A Song for Lya and Other Stories",
        "authors": [
            2
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: thats what i want -> i want to post new book with specific author, for example post a book for author1. see urls.py

Comment: I have edited the question with a different approach since I have never used the approach you have shown above. I managed to assign many books to the same author and you also can display it in the author's endopoint.